# Eclipse plugin Not compatible with older versions

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I developed an eclipse plugin in Eclipse 3.7 RCP plugin development. But during the creation of the project I mentioned that this plugin is intended to work on the 3.6 version . But strangely my plugin is working on Eclipse 3.7 and in 3.3 but NOT in 3.6.

Comment: I would recommend using a build tool such as Maven and m2eclipse/Tycho when developing for Eclipse. In addition to greatly simplifying your builds and dependency management, it makes it very easy to switch your target and start developing against another version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your code over to Eclipse 3.6 and develop your plugin there.

There's no guarantee that every feature of every version of Eclipse works.